# Adding a Folder to Media Library VLC 2.0.5

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

Anyone know how to add a folder to the VLC media library so that the music contents are updated in it whenever the folder is updated? I've seen "Add Folder" options for other versions, but nothing on 2.0.5, the latest build.

Answer (score 3):

** This is MAC specific - using VLC 2.1.4 **

I've found the way to add folders to VLC for Mac is somewhat convoluted.

I didn't want something that links to a real folder, just a virtual folder to put streams under, but as the OP stated, couldn't find an "Add Folder" option (as I have on my windows version).

Instead, what I do is:

1. Create a new folder on my desktop (e.g. "Radio - Other"),
2. Drag that into the Media Library in VLC
3. Place at least 1 item in the folder inside Media Library (otherwise it loses its "folder" like status on restart)
4. Delete the actual empty desktop folder
5. Restart VLC.

The folder remains in VLC as required, and if you right-click and choose "Media Information..." it will have changed the Location to "vlc://nop" which if fine, and can now be used as holding folder for organising the Media Library into hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out! Basically what I did was put a symbolic link in the corresponding folder VLC automatically looks in, an alias won't work. I just adapted the instructions contained in the link below.

So I was interested in having VLC automatically update my movies when I add or delete one, but I have my movies on a secondary HDD not in the default Mac User folder. I just adapted the instructions below to where my movies are then moved the file that was created to the default movies folder in my user account and it worked. Now when I change the movies folder on my secondary HDD it's updated next time VLC is opened! I'm pretty sure this will also work for My Music and My Pictures, but I don't use VLC for that. This was done in OS X Yosemite.

http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=2001110610290643

Answer (score 0):

Open VLC, select Media Library from the sidebar, and drag the folder you want to add into the pane on the right. If 'Media Library' isn't there, enable in Preferences/Show All/Playlist/Use media library. If it's a network folder, it'll have to be mounted or VLC will not add it.